# What is the NEAR Protocol version of ERC20 tokens?

Tags: nearprotocol

The ERC20 token standard (https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20) defines fungible tokens.  What is NEAR's version of this?

Answer (score 5):

NEAR Protocol's version of ERC standards are called NEPs ("NEAR Enhancement Proposals").  The repo is available at https://github.com/nearprotocol/NEPs (likely will move to https://github.com/near/NEPs).

The specific standard for fungible tokens, which is analogous to [ERC20](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20), is called [NEP21](https://github.com/nearprotocol/NEPs/blob/b1f044005491496daee434380349a42129132d7c/specs/Standards/Tokens/FungibleToken.md)

Edit: [Reference walkthrough in the NEAR docs](https://docs.near.org/docs/tutorials/near-studio/token#__docusaurus)

For reference, the *non*fungible token standard, analogous to [ERC721](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721), is [NEP4](https://github.com/nearprotocol/neps/pull/4)

Answer (score 1):

actually these are better references for fungible tokens (ERC20) which is NEP21

https://github.com/near-examples/FT

and a related NFTs (ERC721 or NEP4)

https://github.com/near-examples/NFT